# How to pass UniqueID as constructor args to a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, uuid

I am  a new to spring. I have a bean class with a constructor having single parameter, a uniqueId.

```
void Sample(String uniqueId){
      this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
}
```

the bean doesn't have any default constructor.
I require this id for some bussiness logic.
this uniqueID needs to be UUID.randomUUID().toString().

How can pass this to the bean from the bean configuration xml.

```
<bean id="Sample" class="com.scribe.dao.Sample">
     <constructor-arg  value="UUID.randomUUID().toString()"/>               
</bean>
```

this doesn't work. What are my other options?
I have also seen an example like this in another post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25306467/3492866).`<constructor-arg value="uniqueId"/>`
but the same didnot work for me.Is there any easyway to do this.
any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make use of Spring Expression Language (SpEL) as illustrated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef)

The bean definition should look like below

```
<bean id="Sample" class="com.scribe.dao.Sample">
    <constructor-arg  value="#{ T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString() }"/>               
</bean>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help here :)