# How to register irregular-class beans by hand in Spring

Tags: java, spring

For regular class which has regular fields with regular **getters** and **setters**, Spring's `BeanDefinitionBuilder` and `BeanDefinition` work well.

But for those irregular class (e.g., the class using builder-mode creation), Spring will fail to load these beans due to there is no **setter** function in the class.

The `beanFactory.registerSingleton()` can not suit because I want to register many Objects with the same Class and different names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FactoryBean` to receive all the arguments to your irregular class and then return it from the `getObject()` method.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236850/spring-using-builder-pattern-to-create-a-bean).